# Django load balancing: How to share user media?

Tags: django, load-balancing

With two web servers serving the same Django application with the same underlying database, I could now balance all requests between the two servers.

Sessions are stored in the DB. Static media can be handled the same as if I used a content-delivery network (CDN).

But how do I handle user-uploaded media files that sit on a local filesystem of the webserver that receives the upload POST?
Obviously, the second server will miss these files.

What is a reliable solution? NFS to some third server? Constantly running Unison or using a DVCS like Mercurial oder git?

Answer (score 4):

> Static media can be handled the same as if I used a content-delivery
>   network (CDN).

There is your answer. Upload user media to a CDN. Checkout out [django-storages](https://bitbucket.org/david/django-storages/wiki/Home) for an S3 or Cloudfiles storage backend.

Comment: So the idea is to use S3 or Cloudfiles as the one and only media storage and serving facility and not serve the files myself?

Comment: Yes that's correct. If you have a single load balancer then you could put all the media there (via NFS or otherwise) but once you have more than one load balancer you are back the the same problem. Using S3 for your static and uploaded media is a much more scalable solution in the long run.

Comment: OK thanks, that is not what I want (won't solely rely on cloud storage) but it would work!

Comment: Support for Rackspace CloudFiles in django-storages is deprecated. It mentions [django-cumulus](https://github.com/richleland/django-cumulus) as a valid alternative.

Comment: It looks like it might be returning https://bitbucket.org/david/django-storages/issue/125/

Answer (score 2):

I personally use NFS to a third server, which then serves directly all the media when requested. This reduce the NFS usage to the upload phase, and the media server can be optimized for static assets.